# type of bifurcation occurs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What are the fixed points of

> $$
> θ'=1-a\sinθ
> $$

$$\text{what type of bifurcation occurs at }
a=1, \;\;\;θ=π/2
$$

Solution:

$$
1/a=\sinθ
\text{ or } θ=\arcsin(1/a)
$$

I cant seem to find the proper fixed points after this step

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to find any fixed points analytically to get the answer you are seeking.

Plot the function 
$$
a=\frac{1}{\sin \theta}
$$
in the interval $(\pi/2-\varepsilon,\pi/2+\varepsilon)$. Fixing $a=\hat{a}$ gets you an idea about the number of fixed points and their types (this is called bifurcation diagram).

Note that if $a>1$ then you have two fixed points, one is stable and another is unstable. If $a<1$ then you have no fixed points, the two above approached each other and collapsed. This should be known to you as a *saddle-node*, or *tangent*, or *fold* bifurcation.